# Como usar o FILTER_VALIDATE_IP tratando um array?

Tags: php, html

```
 <input type="text" name="ip[]"/>

<?php
$ip = $_POST['ip'];

if(filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
    echo("$ip is a valid IP address");
   }else {
echo("$ip is not a valid IP address");
}
?>
```

Se eu coloco qualquer ip sem ser array dentro da variável que recebe meu ip e valida tranquilamente,mas quando passo um array,já que o campo de input é dinâmico,o php não aceita a validação.

Já tentei até usar o FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY,mas não deu nada certo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, neste caso você terá como resposta um array, sua variável $ip ficará assim:

```
array(
    0=>ip_1,
    1=>ip_2
    ...
)
```

Para validar isso, você precisará utilizar um laço para percorrer as chaves e validar chave por chave.

Seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
foreach($ip = $i){
    if(filter_var($i, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
        echo("$i is a valid IP address");
    }else {
        echo("$i is not a valid IP address");
    }
}
```

Veja se te ajuda ai.

Abraços

Comment: Deu certo aqui,vlwsss

Comment: Precisando é só gritar ;-)